# How to open a remote file (ssh) with my local Emacs?

Tags: ssh, emacs

I use `ssh` to connect to a remote machine where a file is.

Once the connection is established, if I run `emacs the_file` in the terminal, instead of launching my local Emacs, it opens an editor inside the terminal which is very modest...

Does anyone know how to open this file in a normal emacs session?

Comment: This is a useful answer, worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20624538/2188550

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [tramp](http://www.gnu.org/s/tramp/). Simply start your local emacs, open file (ctrl+x+f) and type the full address like this: `/the.server.name:/the/path/to/the/file`. So assuming the server is at `example.com` and the file at `/home/me/test.txt`, the address to type would be `/example.com:/home/me/test.txt`. This will open the file in the local emacs instance.

(Note that this does not require an additional manual ssh connection.)

Of course there is also the second option to use [sshfs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS) to mount the remote directory on a local address and open the local version.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... when I use `ssh`, I should write `ssh a_name@server`, and enter password... how should I enter this in Emacs?

Comment: got it... I should write `/server:/...` directly which normally includes `a_name`, and Emacs asks me the password... Thank you...

Comment: SoftTimur: can you please give an example with user name included?